# Python: How to access variable declared in parent module

Tags: python, import

Using the structure from the Python docs:

```
sound/
  __init__.py
  effects/
          __init__.py
          echo.py
          surround.py
          reverse.py
```

Say I want to `import sound.effects` and get a list of available effects.  I could do this by declaring a module-level variable in `sound.effects` and then appending to it when each .py file is imported.  So sound/effects/__init__.py might look like this:

```
effectList = []
import echo
import surround   # Could write code to import *.py instead
...
```

From my main code I can now access `sound.effects.effectList` to get a list of effects, but how do I access `effectList` from within echo.py to do the actual append?  I'm stuck trying to get access to the variable:

```
# None of these work :-(
# from . import self
# from .. import effects
# import sound.effects

sound.effect.effectList.append({'name': 'echo'})
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What people commonly do in this situation is create a common.py file in the module.

```
sound/
  __init__.py
  effect/
          __init__.py
          common.py
          echo.py
          surround.py
          reverse.py
```

Then you move the code from `__init__.py` to `common.py`:

```
effectList = []
import echo
import surround   # Could write code to import *.py instead
...
```

Inside `__init__.py` you have this:

```
from common import *
```

So now in `echo.py` you'd have this:

```
import common
common.effectList.append({'name': 'echo'})
```

Anything importing sound would use it like this

```
import sound.effect

for effect_name,effect in sound.effect.effectlist.items():
    #....
```

I've only just started using this myself, but I believe it's common practice in the python community.

Comment: Excellent, that worked perfectly!  Many thanks.  (Just FYI the for loop doesn't run as-is.)

Answer (score 3):

I think you should leave the "making available" to the `__init__.py` inside the `effects` package rather than have all the modules auto populate the `effectList`. A couple of reasons I can think of.

1. You can't import any of the effects except via the package if you did manage to get this work somehow (they'd except an `effectList` in the importing module).
2. You have to manually do the append in every effect you write. It would be better if you just implemented an `import *.py` like thing in your `__init__.py` that loaded everything up in the current directory and made it available.

Something like this in your `__init__.py`.

```
import os, glob

effectslist = []

for i in glob.glob("*.py"):
    if i == "__init__.py":
        next
    print "Attempting to import %s"%i
    try:
        mod = __import__(os.path.splitext(i)[0])
        effectslist.append(mod)
    except ImportError,m:
        print "Error while importing %s - %s"%(i,m)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  In my case it's not sound effects I'm wanting a list of, but static data (a bit like a poor man's database.)  Since nobody will ever want to import just a single "effect" the resulting error is not really a problem.  But I see your point about keeping things separate, maybe I should do all the appending in the init code.  It'll be a bit messier but will keep each sub-module separate.

Comment: You might want to import effect by effect (e.g. for testing etc.). Te other pleasant effect is that all you need to get a new effect is to drop a file into this directory.